# DOM Event - start download after E-Mail has been sent

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, dom

I am struggeling with a DOM Code i want to use with Contact Form 7 on a Wordpresssite of mine.
Here is what i want to do:
After users have sumbitted some personal information they should get a pdf via download.
Currently i just send them to the pdf location, as you can see in the following script:

```
    <script>
       document.addEventListener( 'wpcf7mailsent', function( event ) {
       location = 'path_with_pdf_file';
       }, false );
    </script>
```

Is there some simple codeline i am missing to start the download?
Would appreciate every answer i can get.

Kind regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've prepared 3 solutions for you. I think second one is the easiest and does what you asked.

**Solution 1**

In your case `window.location` will never work unless you make HTTP request and setup headers telling the browser to handle the request as octet stream.

```
// PHP example code
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename=FILENAME.pdf');
header('Content-type: application/pdf');
```

---

**Solution 2**

Your best bet is to create `anchor` element, which holds all your download information and then execute `.click()` method.

Let's prepare our function which will handle everything for us.

```
function downloadFile(path) {
  var fileName = path.split('/').pop();
  // We create anchor
  var element = document.createElement('a');
  // Let's add properties to our anchor
  element.href = path;
  element.download = fileName;
  // Now we fire .click() method
  element.click();
}

document.addEventListener( 'wpcf7mailsent', function( event ) {
  downloadFile('http://domain/path/filename.pdf');
}, false );
```

---

**Solution 3**

Why not send pdf via email? To do it we need to hook to `wpcf7_before_send_mail` action.

Here is code I used which should be working with the latest `CF7`.

```
add_action("wpcf7_before_send_mail", "wpcf7_do_something_else");  
function wpcf7_do_something_else($cf7) {

  $wpcf = WPCF7_ContactForm::get_current();
  $mail = $cf7->prop('mail');
  // Use it if you need to access form Id
  // $wpcf->id;

  // Your attachment do magic here
  $mail['attachments'] .= "\nuploads/regulations.pdf";

  $cf7->set_properties( array( 'mail' => $mail ) );

  return $wpcf;
}
```

Comment: Oh hey, thanks alot. Never thought about your third solutation. It is really the best option in my case! Thank you!